# What’s the name of the historical manhwa where the female lead is a substitute noble?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I once read a historical manhwa where the female lead reincarnates? There, the female lead had to act as a substitute for the noble’s sick daughter (as they look alike). And at last she dies. But afterwards she reincarnates and remembers everything that has happened to her.

Comment: Can you recall any other details, such as how she dies or what she does after reincarnating? I can think of 2 manhwa off the top of my head involving pretending to be a dead noble, but not sick. There's also the story-id checklist [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question).

Comment: So in the memory she had, she thought she was replacing the dead noble (but was actually sick). After the real daughter came back all fine, fl was killed by her knight. So now the story repeats but she now knows who’s real who’s fake. In the present, she was living with her parents in a small hut. Then as she expected, those ppl came and make an offer as a substitute and she went along. She acts like she’s clueless in front of them but she has her plans. I think that’s all I know XD.

Answer (score 3):

This is [Shadow Queen](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shadow-queen).

> “Can you be my daughter for me?” By his offer, Elena became Duke of Franceschi’s fake daughter. ... Then suddenly, Princess Veronica who was assumed dead came back. She was only just a toy. And eventually, Elena gets her son taken and murdered… However,She went back to the past. “I’ll destroy all of you. I’ll never live as a toy again." Elena decides to seeks revenge.

The description summarizes her first life. After dying and reincarnating, she returns to her earlier life with her parents in a small hut. With the knowledge that her patrons are out to get her, she plots her revenge and makes connections while acting clueless in front of the people that killed her.