# Manhwa where the female lead is pretending to be the duke's daughter while the duke's real daughter is sick..?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manhwa when its English translation was just released and now I can't seem to find it. The female lead had light yellow hair (I think) and she resembled the duke's sick daughter exactly, so he 'adopted her' but then got rid of her after his real daughter woke up. The duke basically used her as a placeholder.

Comment: Can you provide details that show this story has science fiction or fantasy elements to it? Also, take a look at our [tour] and [help] for tips on how to ask a good story-id question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

As per [What’s the name of the historical manhwa where the female lead is a substitute noble?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244801/what-s-the-name-of-the-historical-manhwa-where-the-female-lead-is-a-substitute-n), this is likely to be *[Queen in the Shadows](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147630/Queen_in_the_Shadows)*.

[image: Title image for Queen in the Shadows]

> This is not a fairytale. No, this is a story of what lurks beyond the “happily ever after.” Once upon a time, Elena assumed the role of Princess Veronica, married the crown prince, and lived happily... until her dutiful knight plunged his sword into her back and the true Veronica stepped out of the darkness. Now, Elena finds herself at the beginning of her cautionary tale. However, this time she intends to do more than play the star of the show. This time, Elena will direct the downfall of everyone who played a part in wronging her.

As you can see from the title image, she does have blond hair and, as hinted in the discussion, she reincarnates after her initial death to redo the story.

Found with a search for `manhwa girl adopted to portray sick daughter`